# Backbone.js navigation to index url

Tags: backbone.js

I have listing of posts at http://example.com/posts.
Each post has edit link, like

http://example.com/posts#/1/edit

when i click on the link, i am rendering edit post template and saving it. Now the issue is
after updating the post, i want to redirect back http://example.com/posts.

when i do Backbone.history.navigate('/posts', true), i find http://example.com/posts#posts in the url.

May be i am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Backbone's Router to perform the navigation.

You must have set an instance of it in you application (every BB app has one). This is the skeleton code to perform the navigation:

```
AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({ ... }) //should already be set on your app
app = new AppRouter();
app.navigate('/posts', {trigger: true});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am getting the same result. :(

Comment: I made a new router action 'all', like                                                      var route = new window.Message.MessageRouter();
route.navigate('all', { trigger: true});                                           The the route that display over there is /messages#all.Not satisfied completely but working fine.